# Definitions for Dot42 vs standard Android definitions

Tags: c#, android, definition, dot42

This may or may not be a very straightforward question. I've very recently decided to create a number of applications with the android platform in mind, and as such installed Dot42, since C# is the language I'm most proficient in.

I noticed that Visual Studio cannot browse to the definitions for Dot42 or for the dot42 Android sdk. This pretty much means that I can make buttons and do calculations, but cannot do things as complicated as making sounds, playing media, streaming... you get the picture.

Is there a comprehensive definition standard for Android SDK? In particular I'm looking for methods to access components, most of all the media output handle.

If this is the type of question that is frowned upon, I do apologise. Let me know and I'll get rid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire Android API is available. See:
http://docs.dot42.com/Reference/Index

Comment: Is there any reason why this doesn't appear to show in search results? I googled things like "Dot42 android definitions" and similar all night, and yet this is the first I've seen of spmething workable

Comment: Good question. Honestly, I don't know.